# Retrieve records from one table where data in three of four columns are identical?

Tags: sql

Scenario:

One table named "Items"

Six columns: "Item_Num", "Item_Name", "Status", "Aisle", "Bin" & "Qty"

The goal is to ensure "Item_Num"/"Item_Name" with the same "Status" reside in the same "Aisle" and "Bin" location; however, there can be an instance where two boxes of the same "Item_Num"/"Item_Name" and "Status" could be in separate "Aisle" and Bin" locations.  I want to be able to run a query for the system to return the records where "Item_Num", "Item_Name" and "Status" are identical, but the "Aisle" and "Bin" data does not match.

```
Item_Num | Item_Name   |    Status   |   Aisle   |   Bin   |  Qty
5206     | Popcorn     |      A      |     1     |    2    |   5
5206     | Popcorn     |      A      |     1     |    3    |   4
5206     | Popcorn     |      A      |     2     |    2    |   5
5206     | Popcorn     |      B      |     1     |    4    |   2
```

In the example above, I would like the system to return the rows where the first columns match.  This would allow for consolidation of three items into one location.

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select a.Item_num,a.Item_Name,a.Status,a.Aisle,a.Bin,a.qty from table a inner join table b
ON a.Item_num=b.Item_num and a.Item_Name=b.Item_Name and a.Status=b.Status and a.Aisle <> b.Aisle and a.Bin <> b.Bin
```

Answer (score 0):

First get find which item record groups have multiple aisle, bin values.  Then return any rows  belonging to those groups.

```
with g as
( select item_num, item_name, status,
         count(distinct aisle) as aisles,
         count(distinct bin)   as bins
    from items
    group by item_num, item_name, status
    having count(distinct aisle) > 1
        or count(distinct bin)   > 1
)
select i.item_num, i.item_name, i.status, 
       i.aisle, i.bin,
       sum(1.qty) tot_qty
  from items i
  join g        on  (i.item_num, i.item_name, i.status)
                   =(g.item_num, g.item_name, g.status)
  group by item_num, item_name, status, aisle, bin
```